# HTML page on load should open a default phone dial screen with phone number

Tags: redirect, meta-tags, http-redirect, tel

I have URL https://www.example.com/phonecall

When the user opens this link on a Mobile device (Andriod, iPhone) the page should redirect to the Phone dialer with phone number 1-999-999-9999.

I do not care so much about the desktop experience.

Any help would be great

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting that in your code :

```
<script>
window.location = "tel:+1(999)9999999"
</script>
```

I actually didnt test it, but I think it is right.

EDIT : Just tested it, it perfectly worked. Basically, the "link" to open a phone dial is `tel:phonenumber`.